# Opening and closing form2 from form1 C#

Tags: c#

I have a main form called form1 that I want to keep always visible, and I want to be able to show and hide form2 from a button (or two) that's in form1.
How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Is `Form2` modal? If it is then that makes things simpler.

Comment: Have you tried `Form form2 = new Form(); form2.Show(); form2.Close()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this on your `Form1`

```
private Form2 _form2;

public void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(_form2 == null)
     _form2 = new Form2();
  _form2.Show();
}

public void btnHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(_form2 != null)
     _form2.Hide();
}
```

But im not sure `Form2` can be shown, again if it is ever closed. (i works fine if `Form2` is just hidden)

Answer (score 2):

Create a new instance of `Form2` in your button `Click` handler in `Form1` and call `Show()` on that instance to show the form.  Keep a hold of that instance, because you'll want to call the `Close()` method on it later to close it down.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use

```
using(Form2 frm = new Form2())
{
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

this way the form gets correctly disposed when finished with.

Comment: `Form` instance will be disposed when it's closed. Thus, I think that it's no need to use the `using` technique here.

Comment: @Tu Tran - Not necessarily, this disposes the form straight away when finished with. ["The two conditions when a form is not disposed on Close...you have displayed the form using ShowDialog"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx)...

Comment: @Sayse agree! you should dispose a form then it is called with `ShowDialog()`. If it is just called with `Show()`, it will auto dispose

Answer (score 0):

```
form2 f2=new form2(form1_Parent);
f2.ShowDialog();
f2.Close();
```

Comment: `ShowDialog` method makes `f2` modal, thus `f2.Close()` statement won't reach util `f2` is closed.

Comment: @TuTran, ridiculous. f2.Close() can be fired from a button click in f2, what hell is your downvote for? Note that the above code is not sequentially executed, it is code snippet, snippet!

Comment: I don't want to create a war here. Let others see why I did that.

Comment: @TuTran, who wants to "create a war"? what do you mean? What 's the sense of your above comment?