# Error CS1674 trying to open second form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm sure, this is a total newbie question, but I'm hanging for hours now...

My main form should have a method that opens a second form with a textbox. Just to have a kind of messagebox with scrollbar. I know there are lots of examples out there, but they are all too extensive for my needs. So here is my code so far:

```
private void ShowBox (string info)
{
    if (info != "")
    {
        using (var form = new Message())
        {
             // work to do
        }
    }
}

public partial class Message : Form 
{ 
    public Message() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
        say.Text = "OK"; 
    }
}
```

Message is my 2nd form. I receive CS1674 (type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable') error on the using line.
I already took this as reference [Opening and closing form2 from form1 C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102294/opening-and-closing-form2-from-form1-c-sharp) but I don't see the difference to my code.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Message` probably resolves as `System.Windows.Forms.Message` which is a structure.

Ctrl+Click on your usage of new Message() will jump to the declaration.

Comment: or press `F12`, depending on the settings

Answer (score 0):

In namespace `System.Windows.Forms` there is already a struct named Message. Seems like the compiler confounds your class with that. You should rename your form to something like `MessageForm`.

Comment: hm... Message is the second form. I post the code here:

 `public partial class Message : Form
    {
        public Message()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            say.Text = "OK";
        }`